# I do not get native selenium error such as 'Element not Found' or 'Element is not clickable'.Instead i get timeout error in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm working in Protractor cucumber framework.I do not get native selenium errors such as 'Element not Found' or 'No Such Element Found' or 'Element is not clickable' if the element is not found in page or not clickable.Instead i get "TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 10002ms"

Only if i get these errors I will come to know i have made some mistake in my element xpath or I have tried to click a disabled button etc.

Generic error like time out does not help me fix the failed test cases easily.

Below is my code.contactPage.js is the implementation.util.js is some helper methods in my framework

File contactPage.js

```
  var contact = element(by.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Contact Me')]"));

   function clickUserGuide() {
   return util.isDisplayed(contact, 10000).then(() => {
    return util.clickElement(contact, 10000);
});
```

File util.js

```
function isDisplayed(element, milliseconds) {
return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), milliseconds).then(() => {
    return element.isDisplayed();
  });
};
function clickElement(element, milliseconds) {
 return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), milliseconds).then(() => {
    element.click();
    return true;
 });
}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting `TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 10002ms` is because of the method `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), milliseconds)` you are using.

The method doesn't have a fail "hard" like the `No Such Element Found`, it just keeps waiting for the element to match the expected condition, in your case you are waiting for:

1. the element is be displayed
2. AND the height and width to be greater than 0

If this doesn't happen in the given amount of seconds the condition fails with a message that the element couldn't match the condition within the given time.

What happens is you use `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), milliseconds)`, is the element really present in the DOM?

Comment: In a scenario where there is a typo in the xpath during the development, the test case fails giving out the timeout error. But i expect a error which says the 'Element is not found'. So i can get with your answer saying due to wait() im getting time out error.. But wait is also required in all scenarios. I want result from return element.isDisplayed(); saying the element is not found. Should i add this as a promise like  return  element.isDisplayed().then((result)=>{return result});  ????

Comment: If you need to wait on an element to appear with the `browser.wait()` and you don't provide the correct xpath then you will never get the error. So there is no other solution than only using the correct xpath